# If one value is null get previous value in that quarter, in sql select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by

I have data as shown below,

[image]

Now i want to get result as ,

```
DateDisplayName  Active
Q2(Jun)-2015     736
Q3(Sep)-2015     734
Q4(Dec)-2015     NULL
Q1(Mar)-2016     NULL
```

So if last month data is null in that quarter then get last but one data.
Ex: in Q3 Active is null for Sep so i shoul show Aug data.

Comment: Where is there August data?  And which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: If you look at  above picture, you can see a record with 201508 which is 2015Aug data, but we are marking it as Q3(Sep)-2015.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: And if there are two NULLs in a quarter, which data do you want to use?

Comment: 1st month in that quarter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd rank your records. Use `ROW_NUMBER` to give the best record per quarter row number 1 and then only keep those.

```
select 
  date_display_name, 
  active
from
(
  select
    date_display_name, 
    active,
    row_number() over 
    (
      partition by date_display_name 
      order by 
        case when active is null then 2 else 1 end,
        defaultdate desc
    ) as rn
  from mytable
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```